# Accordian menu and website responsivity

Tags: html, css

for my website i did an accordian menu horizontal. I take inspiration from some code on the internet.
The problem is that is not responsive. If a person Zoom in, half of the menu disappear.
There's a way to use change it, maybe when the resolution is too low?
I tried with:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 900px) {
   #menu{
     display:none;
 } 
}
```

But it doesn't work. Because i can put a drop down menu if the resolution is too low.

http://jsfiddle.net/2SRg4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do a couple things here, first you should make sure you have a meta viewport tag in order to control device zooming for a responsive design. Use something like this

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

Secondly your meta tag is for devices only  so if you are testing on your computer it wont work. Use `@media (max-width: 900px) { }` if you want it responsive on your computer as well as devices

**UPDATE**

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/A8ynL/

**HTML**

```
<div id="mainMenu"><!-- Stuff --></div>
<div id="phoneMenu"><!-- Stuff --></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#mainMenu { width: 100%; height: 50px; background-color: green; display: block; }
#phoneMenu { display: none; }

@media (max-width: 900px) {
    #mainMenu { display: none; }
    #phoneMenu { display: block; width: 100%; height: 50px; background-color: blue; }
}
```

**Page Structure**

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<title>Title</title>
<style>
/*Normal CSS*/
@media (max-width: 900px) {
 /*Responsive CSS*/
}
</style>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you, i am really not used with responsive. So i can put a media max width for desktop and a media device-width per i device? or the first one override the second in every case?

And last question: To change the menu with another, how can i do after the first one is display:none i should add in media{display :block;} to a previous hided menu?

Comment: dont add another @media query of 900 unless you need device specific styling. Just change the one you have to the one I posted, dont forget to add the meta tag into your page or you will have conflicts when you look at your page on your website. Check the jsfiddle I posted and expand and contract your browser to see the div change from green to blue

Comment: astonishing +++
so media(maxwidth) work on both device and desktop PC. while media max-device-width just work in phone?